# ui.datepicker.js calendar autoUpdate another calendar when date change

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker, onchange, auto-update

I'm using **ui.datepicker.js**

In my edit form I have 2 calendars that have their own function.

Calendar A : is the date that the invoiced is created
Calendar B : is the date for next billing
Bill_freq is the field where is set the billing frequency (every 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 12 months)

What I want to do is when date is changed on **Calendar A**, 
**Calender B** will be updated automatically to a date base on **Bill_freq** field.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myCalendarA').datepicker({
   //other options here
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {  
       //pick the value you need
       var billFreq = $('#Bill_freq').val();  
       //do some calculation with dateText (selected date in CalA) and billFreq
       var newDate = dateText + billFreq;  //beware date calc in JS is hard to master
       //sets the date for Calendar B           
       $('#myCalendarB').datepicker('setDate', newDate) ;
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
 
I have tried your code without success...
the calendar stop working after 

Any clue?

Comment: You have to add the `onSelect` parameter in the first call you do to activate datepicker.

Comment: Hi, I have 4 calendars ont his form,  the first 2 are regular calendar.. Do you mean I have to add onSelect on the first one?

Comment: Yes, because it is the one that, when changed, will change the second calendar. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: yes this is what I need. I will make other tests today maybe I'm missing something. There are 2 others calender on the form that are regular single calender that are in the begginning of the form maybe this is what causing the problem...

Comment: Do I need to give a second class name for both calender or use the same class name?

Comment: Calendars are pretty unique elements in forms. I usually give them all different IDs, rather than using classes to select them. As in the above example, `#myCalendarA` is the first one, `#myCalendarB` is the second one. You have to add the *special* `onSelect` only in `myCalendarA`. The other ones can work as before (be sure to use a different `.datepicker` call for them!)

Comment: Ok I see, I have fixed it, now calendar are ok, but it still doing nothing to CalendarB if I changed CalenderA.
The value for billFreq are arrays and stored in the BD like this 30 for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

try something like `onchange="$('#Calenderb').val($('#Calendera').val())"`

Comment: Hi mnml,

How to set the date base on Bill_freq value?